Simple parsing of JSON timestamp not working in FluentBit
Given a simple fluent bit config, I am trying to achieve, that the timestamp of the log entry should the parsed from the JSON. Obviously I am missing something very basic.
[SERVICE]
    Parsers_File parsers.conf
    Log_Level debug

[INPUT]
    Name dummy
    Dummy {"foo":"bar", "time":"2024-08-29T08:51:25.0000Z"}


[FILTER]
    Name parser
    Match *
    Key_Name message
    Parser vault


[OUTPUT]
    Name          stdout

and a parsers.conf:
[PARSER]
    Name          vault
    Format        json
    Time_Key      time
    Time_Format   %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ

Running this gives the following output, which does not seem to parse the timestamp...
Fluent Bit v3.1.6
* Copyright (C) 2015-2024 The Fluent Bit Authors
* Fluent Bit is a CNCF sub-project under the umbrella of Fluentd
* https://fluentbit.io

______ _                  _    ______ _ _           _____  __
|  ___| |                | |   | ___ (_) |         |____ |/  |
| |_  | |_   _  ___ _ __ | |_  | |_/ /_| |_  __   __   / /`| |
|  _| | | | | |/ _ \ '_ \| __| | ___ \ | __| \ \ / /   \ \ | |
| |   | | |_| |  __/ | | | |_  | |_/ / | |_   \ V /.___/ /_| |_
\_|   |_|\__,_|\___|_| |_|\__| \____/|_|\__|   \_/ \____(_)___/

[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] Configuration:
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]  flush time     | 1.000000 seconds
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]  grace          | 5 seconds
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]  daemon         | 0
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] ___________
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]  inputs:
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]      dummy
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] ___________
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]  filters:
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]      parser.0
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] ___________
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]  outputs:
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]      stdout.0
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] ___________
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info]  collectors:
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] [fluent bit] version=3.1.6, commit=, pid=46896
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [debug] [engine] coroutine stack size: 36864 bytes (36.0K)
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] [storage] ver=1.5.2, type=memory, sync=normal, checksum=off, max_chunks_up=128
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] [cmetrics] version=0.9.4
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] [ctraces ] version=0.5.5
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] [input:dummy:dummy.0] initializing
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] [input:dummy:dummy.0] storage_strategy='memory' (memory only)
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [debug] [dummy:dummy.0] created event channels: read=21 write=22
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [debug] [stdout:stdout.0] created event channels: read=23 write=24
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] [output:stdout:stdout.0] worker #0 started
[2024/08/29 15:27:24] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
[2024/08/29 15:27:26] [debug] [task] created task=0x600003b74000 id=0 OK
[2024/08/29 15:27:26] [debug] [output:stdout:stdout.0] task_id=0 assigned to thread #0
[0] dummy.0: [[1724938045.737938000, {}], {"foo"=>"bar", "time"=>"2024-08-29T08:51:25.0000Z"}]
[2024/08/29 15:27:26] [debug] [out flush] cb_destroy coro_id=0
[2024/08/29 15:27:26] [debug] [task] destroy task=0x600003b74000 (task_id=0)
[2024/08/29 15:27:27] [debug] [task] created task=0x600003b74000 id=0 OK
[2024/08/29 15:27:27] [debug] [output:stdout:stdout.0] task_id=0 assigned to thread #0
[0] dummy.0: [[1724938046.738413000, {}], {"foo"=>"bar", "time"=>"2024-08-29T08:51:25.0000Z"}]
[2024/08/29 15:27:27] [debug] [out flush] cb_destroy coro_id=1
[2024/08/29 15:27:27] [debug] [task] destroy task=0x600003b74000 (task_id=0)
[2024/08/29 15:27:28] [debug] [task] created task=0x600003b78000 id=0 OK
[2024/08/29 15:27:28] [debug[0] dummy.0: [[1724938047.737795000, {}], {"foo"=>"bar", "time"=>"2024-08-29T08:51:25.0000Z"}]
] [output:stdout:stdout.0] task_id=0 assigned to thread #0
[2024/08/29 15:27:28] [debug] [out flush] cb_destroy coro_id=2
[2024/08/29 15:27:28] [debug] [task] destroy task=0x600003b78000 (task_id=0)
^C[2024/08/29 15:27:28] [engine] caught signal (SIGINT)
[2024/08/29 15:27:28] [ info] [input] pausing dummy.0
[2024/08/29 15:27:28] [ info] [output:stdout:stdout.0] thread worker #0 stopping...
[2024/08/29 15:27:28] [ info] [output:stdout:stdout.0] thread worker #0 stopped

